# QGIS: using non-square SVG

Tags: print-composer, svg, qgs

I am using QGIS 3.10 and would like to visualise my data using a custom svg whose source code is:

`<svg enable-background="new 0 0 175 375" height="375" viewBox="0 0 175 375" width="175" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> <path d="m 40.445708,15.5 c 0,0 30,85 -15,165 -36.897041,65.59474 -20.0000005,115 -10,135 C 44.514588,373.63777 150,365 170.4457,305.5 190.99887,245.68723 189.06791,170.62949 40.445708,15.5 Z" fill="param(fill)" fill-opacity="param(fill-opacity)" stroke="param(outline)" stroke-opacity="param(outline-opacity)" stroke-width="param(outline-width)"/> </svg>`.

In QGIS the .svg is displayed correctly and can be adjusted as I wish:

[image]

In the print composer, this .svg is distorted into a square:

[image]

How can I prevent this?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem in QGIS 3.14.1, using an SVG based on the source code above. However, everything works perfectly, no distortion to a square in print composer. Could you give some more details?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a simple workaround using Inkscape: making the window square and aligning it.